# ajax with dry technique for multiple modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am trying to make a ajax request to handle multiple modal without repeating the ajax code. Although modal is working fine just want to know, is there any way that i don't have to write jquery code again

**here is my jquery.js**

```
  $(document).on("click", "#modal-btn", function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "transfer_transactions/new",
    dataType: "script",
    success: (response) => {
      console.log(response);
      $("#modal-content").html(response);
    },
  });
});
```

here is my transaction/index.html.haml

```
    = link_to 'New', new_transfer_transaction_path,  id:"modal-btn",  remote: true , :'data-target' => "#exampleModalStaticBackdrop", :'data-toggle' => "modal"
//index code...
    #exampleModalStaticBackdrop.modal{"data-animations" => "fadeInDown, fadeOutUp", "data-static-backdrop" => ""}          
      .modal-dialog.max-w-2xl
        .modal-content
          .modal-header
            %button.close.la.la-times{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"}
          .modal-body
            #modal-content
```

i want to use this modal in country/index.html.haml without repeating the ajax code again. Is there any way?

Comment: Sure create a named javascript function and then pass in the variable data e.g. `$(document).on("click", "#modal-btn", myModalContentFunction("transfer_transactions/new"))` then move the ajax into `myModalContentFunction`